# "There was a problem parsing the package" - How to solve this?

Tags: java, android, in-app-update

I have an updated app in my device storage. I have to install that upper version app from my existing lower version app in a button click. (Like the way **dora tv** users update their app)
I wrote this code.But it's showing - "There was a problem parsing the package".
There is no error in logcat & no exception. What i need to do now?
[App Install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeKe0.jpg)

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestPermission() {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
    }

    private void havePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
                && !getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {

            Intent unknownAppSourceIntent = new Intent()
                    .setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES)
                    .setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName())));

            startActivityForResult(unknownAppSourceIntent, Constants.APP_INSTALL_REQUEST);
            //unknownAppSourceDialog.launch(unknownAppSourceIntent);
        } else {
            apkInstall();
        }
    }

  private void apkInstall() {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + File.separator + "test.apk";

        Log.d("filePath", path);
        File file = new File(path);

        if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
            // do something
            Log.d("fileExist", file.getName());
        }
        Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setData(apkUri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.APP_INSTALL_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            BizUiUtils.showToast(this, "Error in installing App, please try again");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Constants.APP_INSTALL_REQUEST) {
            apkInstall();
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line does it give you an error?

Comment: Not in any line. All statements executed successfully. After execution that error pops up on screen. See the attached image please.

Comment: Have you seen the logs? There would be something for sure. Something wont fail without giving any errors/warnings.

Comment: Thanks brother. There was a log. It was permission related issue. As I was trying to read the apk file from device external storage.